gstreamer appsrc pipeline can output to file, but not to rtsp server
Brief Overview
I am building an application which can take in raw image frames, perform some analysis on them, modify the data, and output back to rtsp. I want to use a gstreamer pipeline to produce the raw image frames from rtsp, and then a second pipeline to encode the images and output them back to rtsp. I have made a test repo to make sure this process works.
The appsink pipeline appears to work fine:
rtspsrc location=\"rtsp://testurl:554/car\" ! queue ! rtph264depay ! queue ! h264parse ! queue ! omxh264dec ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, format=NV12 , framerate=30/1 ! appsink name=nv12_app_sink

I am taking the buffers produced by the above pipeline, copying them, and then passing them through a custom queue to an app source pipeline. The app source appears to work fine when printing to a file:
appsrc name=nv12_frame_source ! queue ! omxh264enc qp-mode=auto control-rate=low-latency target-bitrate=3000 gop-length=60 gop-mode=low-delay-p gdr-mode=horizontal cpb-size=200 num-slices=8 periodicity-idr=270 initial-delay=100 filler-data=false min-qp=15 max-qp=40 b-frames=0 low-bandwidth=false ! video/x-h264, alignment=au ! queue ! filesink location=./out.h264 async=false

However, when I modify the mainloop setup and the pipeline to output to a GstRTSPServer, with the following pipeline passed to gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch:
( appsrc name=nv12_frame_source ! queue ! omxh264enc qp-mode=auto control-rate=low-latency target-bitrate=3000 gop-length=60 gop-mode=low-delay-p gdr-mode=horizontal cpb-size=200 num-slices=8 periodicity-idr=270 initial-delay=100 filler-data=false min-qp=15 max-qp=40 b-frames=0 low-bandwidth=false ! video/x-h264, alignment=au ! queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )

I receive the following error shortly after connecting to the gstreamer server with VLC:
0:00:12.276988200 20894 0xffff30003360 ERROR              fdmemory gstfdmemory.c:126:gst_fd_mem_map::0xffff28009020: fd 776810496: mmap failed: Bad file descriptor
0:00:12.277155034 20894 0xffff30003360 ERROR         omxbufferpool gstomxbufferpool.c:454:gst_omx_buffer_pool_alloc_buffer:<omxbufferpool1> dmabuf memory is not mappable but caps does not have the 'memory:DMABuf' feature
0:00:12.277195464 20894 0xffff30003360 WARN             bufferpool gstbufferpool.c:305:do_alloc_buffer:<omxbufferpool1> alloc function failed
0:00:12.277226645 20894 0xffff30003360 WARN             bufferpool gstbufferpool.c:338:default_start:<omxbufferpool1> failed to allocate buffer
0:00:12.277426768 20894 0xffff30003360 ERROR            bufferpool gstbufferpool.c:559:gst_buffer_pool_set_active:<omxbufferpool1> start failed
0:00:12.277461739 20894 0xffff30003360 ERROR               basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3182:gst_base_src_set_allocation:<nv12_frame_source> failed to activate bufferpool.
0:00:12.277690823 20894 0xffff30003360 WARN                basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3127:gst_base_src_loop:<nv12_frame_source> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:12.277727704 20894 0xffff30003360 WARN                basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3127:gst_base_src_loop:<nv12_frame_source> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
0:00:12.277943218 20894 0xffff38005000 WARN              rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:3250:default_handle_message: 0xffffa80ae970: got error Internal data stream error. (../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstBin:bin0/GstAppSrc:nv12_frame_source: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4))

This error does not appear when a full pipeline is used (see below for details) and so I believe I am setting up the app source incorrectly. However, I am stumped as to why DMA buffer allocation becomes an issue when outputting to rtsp and not when outputting to a file. Can someone help me understand where I might be going wrong?
Other tests
When I use the gstreamer server with exactly the same configuration as previously except no app source, but rather a full pipeline as below:
( rtspsrc location=\"rtsp://myrtspserver:554/test\" ! queue ! rtph264depay ! queue ! h264parse ! queue ! omxh264dec ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, format=NV12 , framerate=30/1 ! queue ! omxh264enc qp-mode=auto control-rate=low-latency target-bitrate=3000 gop-length=60 gop-mode=low-delay-p gdr-mode=horizontal cpb-size=200 num-slices=8 periodicity-idr=270 initial-delay=100 filler-data=false min-qp=15  max-qp=40 b-frames=0 low-bandwidth=false ! perf ! video/x-h264, alignment=au ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )

The rtsp server works fine and I can connect to it with VLC without issue. Thus, it is only the introduction of the appsrc nv12_frame_source which causes the issue, as we can see in the errors which are related to pool allocation for the appsrc.
Full code
Below is the full code I am using, which is split in 3 files:
// video_sink_gst.h
#pragma once

#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

// gst headers
#include <gst/app/gstappsrc.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-server.h>
#include <gst/video/video.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

std::string exec(const char* cmd);

class GSTThreadSafeQueue
{
private:
  std::queue<GstBuffer*> q;
  mutable std::mutex m;
  unsigned int s;

public:
  GSTThreadSafeQueue(unsigned int size = 0) : q(), m(), s(size) {}
  ~GSTThreadSafeQueue(void) {}

  void enqueue(GstBuffer* t)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    auto size_ = q.size();
    if (s > 0 && size_ >= s) {
      GstBuffer* val = q.front();
      gst_buffer_unref(val);
      q.pop(); // TODO this should not be silent
    }
    q.push(t);
  }

  bool dequeue(GstBuffer* &val)
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if (q.empty()) {
      return false;
    }
    val = q.front();
    q.pop();
    return true;
  }

  int get_size(void)
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    auto size_ = q.size();
    return int(size_);
  }
};

struct VideoSinkGSTOptions
{
  std::string out_type;
  std::string rate_control_mode;
  guint target_bitrate;
  guint gop_length;
  std::string gop_mode;
  guint bframes;
  guint img_width;
  guint img_height;
};

class VideoSinkGST
{
private:
  typedef struct _GSTData
  {
    GMainContext* contxt;
    GMainLoop* main_loop;
    GstElement* appsrc;
    GSTThreadSafeQueue* thread_in_q = NULL;
    VideoSinkGSTOptions* options;
  } GSTData;

  GSTData data;
  std::thread worker_thread;

  static std::vector<std::string> GetIp();
  static void clientConnected(GstRTSPServer* server, GstRTSPClient* client, GSTData* data);
  static void media_configure(GstRTSPMediaFactory* factory, GstRTSPMedia* media, GSTData* data);
  static void push_data(GstElement* appsrc, guint size, GSTData* data);
  static void worker(GSTData* data);

public:
  VideoSinkGST(VideoSinkGSTOptions* videosinkoptions, GSTThreadSafeQueue* in_queue) { data.thread_in_q = in_queue; data.options = videosinkoptions; }
  ~VideoSinkGST();
  void initialize(std::string& err_str);
};

// video_sink_gst.cc
#include "video_sink_gst.h"

std::string exec(const char* cmd)
{
  std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(popen(cmd, "r"), pclose);
  if (!pipe)
    return "ERROR";
  char buffer[128];
  std::string result = "";
  while (!feof(pipe.get())) {
    if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe.get()) != NULL)
      result += buffer;
  }
  return result;
}

std::vector<std::string> VideoSinkGST::GetIp()
{
  std::string s = exec("ifconfig | grep 'inet ' | sed 's/.*inet *\\([^ ]*\\).*/\\1/'");

  std::vector<std::string> rarray;
  std::size_t pos;
  while ((pos = s.find("\n")) != std::string::npos) {
    std::string token = s.substr(0, pos);
    if (token != "127.0.0.1") {
      rarray.push_back(token);
    }
    s.erase(0, pos + std::string("\n").length());
  }

  return rarray;
}

void VideoSinkGST::clientConnected(GstRTSPServer* server, GstRTSPClient* client, GSTData* data)
{
  g_print("%s\n", __func__);
}

void VideoSinkGST::media_configure(GstRTSPMediaFactory* factory, GstRTSPMedia* media, GSTData* data)
{
  GstElement* element;

  g_print("%s\n", __func__);
  element      = gst_rtsp_media_get_element(media);
  data->appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name_recurse_up(GST_BIN(element), "nv12_frame_source");
  if (!data->appsrc || !GST_IS_APP_SRC(data->appsrc)) {
    g_print("Issue grabbing GStreamer appsrc");
  }
  gst_util_set_object_arg(G_OBJECT(data->appsrc), "format", "time");
  // clang-format off
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data->appsrc), "caps",
      gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw",
          "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "NV12",
          "width", G_TYPE_INT, data->options->img_width,
          "height", G_TYPE_INT, data->options->img_height,
          "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1, 
          NULL), 
      NULL);
  // clang-format on
  g_signal_connect(data->appsrc, "need-data", G_CALLBACK(push_data), data);
  gst_object_unref(element);
}

void VideoSinkGST::push_data(GstElement* appsrc, guint size, GSTData* data)
{
  static unsigned int frame_no = 1;
  GstBuffer* buffer;
  GstFlowReturn ret;
  std::cout << "received need-data" << std::endl;

  while (!data->thread_in_q->dequeue(buffer)) {
    /* Queue is empty, wait a while */
    usleep(
      50); 
  }

  g_signal_emit_by_name(data->appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
  gst_buffer_unref(buffer);
  std::cout << "VideoSink processed frame " << frame_no << std::endl;

  if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
    /* We got some error, stop sending data */
    std::cout << "GStreamer emit got error: " << ret << std::endl;
    // return;
  }
  frame_no++;
}

void VideoSinkGST::initialize(std::string& err_str)
{
  GstRTSPServer* server;
  GstRTSPMountPoints* mounts;
  GstRTSPMediaFactory* factory;

  gst_init(NULL, NULL);

  std::stringstream pipeline_ss;
  /* App source */
  pipeline_ss << "( ";
  pipeline_ss << "appsrc name=nv12_frame_source ";
  /* Encoder */
  pipeline_ss << "! queue ! omx" << data.options->out_type << "enc ";
  pipeline_ss << "qp-mode=auto ";
  pipeline_ss << "control-rate=" << data.options->rate_control_mode << " ";
  if (data.options->target_bitrate) {
    pipeline_ss << "target-bitrate=" << data.options->target_bitrate << " ";
  }
  pipeline_ss << "gop-length=" << data.options->gop_length << " ";
  pipeline_ss
    << "gop-mode=low-delay-p gdr-mode=horizontal cpb-size=200 num-slices=8 periodicity-idr=270 ";
  pipeline_ss
    << "initial-delay=100 filler-data=false min-qp=15 max-qp=40 b-frames=0 low-bandwidth=false ";
  /* Video sink */
  pipeline_ss << "! video/x-" << data.options->out_type << ", alignment=au ";
  /* Rtsp out */
  pipeline_ss << "! queue ! rtp" << data.options->out_type << "pay name=pay0 pt=96 ";
  pipeline_ss << ")";
  std::cout << "============ PIPELINE ===========\n" << pipeline_ss.str() << std::endl;

  data.contxt    = g_main_context_new();
  data.main_loop = g_main_loop_new(data.contxt, FALSE);

  server = gst_rtsp_server_new();
  g_object_set(server, "service", "554", NULL);

  mounts  = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points(server);
  factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new();

  gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(factory, pipeline_ss.str().c_str());
  gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared(factory, TRUE);
  gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory(mounts, "/test", factory);
  g_object_unref(mounts);

  if (!gst_rtsp_server_attach(server, data.contxt)) {
    err_str = "Issue attaching RTSP server";
    g_main_loop_unref(data.main_loop);
    return;
  }

  g_signal_connect(server, "client-connected", G_CALLBACK(clientConnected), &data);
  g_signal_connect(factory, "media-configure", (GCallback)media_configure, &data);

  worker_thread = std::thread(VideoSinkGST::worker, &data);

  std::vector<std::string> ips = GetIp();
  std::ostringstream addr("");
  static char* port = (char*)"554";
  for (auto& ip : ips) {
    addr << "rtsp://" << ip << ":554/test\n";
  }
  g_print("stream ready at:\n%s", addr.str().c_str());
}

void VideoSinkGST::worker(GSTData* data)
{
  g_main_context_push_thread_default(data->contxt);
  std::cout << "Starting main loop" << std::endl;
  g_main_loop_run(data->main_loop);
  std::cout << "Finished main loop" << std::endl;
  g_main_context_pop_thread_default(data->contxt);
}

VideoSinkGST::~VideoSinkGST()
{
  std::cout << "Stopping main loop" << std::endl;
  GSource* idle_source = g_idle_source_new();
  g_source_set_callback(idle_source, (GSourceFunc)g_main_loop_quit, data.main_loop, NULL);
  g_source_attach(idle_source, data.contxt);
  g_source_unref(idle_source);

  do {
    try {
      (worker_thread).join();
    } catch (const ::std::system_error& e) {
      if (e.code() != std::errc::invalid_argument) {
        std::cerr << "thread:" << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__
                  << " - exception would have caused terminate.";
      }
    }
  } while (0);

  std::cout << "Removing references to main loop and context" << std::endl;
  gst_object_unref(data.appsrc);
  g_main_loop_unref(data.main_loop);
  g_main_context_unref(data.contxt);
}

// enc_test.cc
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "video_sink_gst.h"
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>

class VideoSourceGST
{
private:
  typedef struct _GSTData
  {
    GstElement* pipeline = NULL;
    GstElement* appsink  = NULL;
  } GSTData;

  GSTData data;
  GSTThreadSafeQueue* thread_out_q;

  static GstFlowReturn new_sample(GstAppSink* appsink, GSTThreadSafeQueue* out_queue);

public:
  void initialize();
  VideoSourceGST(GSTThreadSafeQueue* out_queue) : thread_out_q(out_queue) {}
  ~VideoSourceGST();
};

// The callback function
GstFlowReturn VideoSourceGST::new_sample(GstAppSink* appsink,
                                         GSTThreadSafeQueue* out_queue)
{
  static unsigned int frame_no = 1;
  GstSample* sample            = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(appsink);
  GstBuffer* buffer            = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
  GstBuffer* buffer_copy = gst_buffer_copy(buffer);
  out_queue->enqueue(buffer_copy);
  gst_sample_unref(sample);
  std::cout << "VideoSource Processed frame " << frame_no << std::endl;

  frame_no++;
  return GST_FLOW_OK;
}

void VideoSourceGST::initialize()
{
  gst_init(NULL, NULL);

  // Build the pipeline
  // clang-format off
  data.pipeline = gst_parse_launch(
      "rtspsrc location=\"rtsp://myrtspserver:554/test\" ! queue "
      "! rtph264depay ! queue ! h264parse ! queue ! omxh264dec ! video/x-raw, "
      "width=1920, height=1080, format=NV12 , framerate=30/1 ! appsink "
      "name=nv12_app_sink",
      NULL);
  // clang-format on

  // Get the appsink element
  data.appsink = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(data.pipeline), "nv12_app_sink");
  // clang-format off
  GstCaps* video_caps = gst_caps_new_simple(  
    "video/x-raw", 
    "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "NV12", 
    "width", G_TYPE_INT, 1920,
    "height", G_TYPE_INT, 1080, 
    "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1, 
    NULL
  );
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.appsink), 
               "emit-signals", TRUE, 
               "sync", FALSE, 
               "caps", video_caps,
               NULL
  );
  // clang-format on
  g_signal_connect(data.appsink, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK(new_sample), thread_out_q);
  gst_caps_unref(video_caps);

  // Start playing
  gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
}

VideoSourceGST::~VideoSourceGST()
{
  std::cout << "Stopping pipeline" << std::endl;
  gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

  std::cout << "Removing references to pipeline" << std::endl;
  g_object_unref(data.appsink);
  gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(data.pipeline));
}

static void sigint_handler(int signum);
volatile static int done = 0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  VideoSinkGSTOptions gst_options;

  gst_options.out_type          = "h264";
  gst_options.rate_control_mode = "low-latency";
  gst_options.gop_mode          = "basic";
  gst_options.target_bitrate    = (guint)3000;
  gst_options.gop_length        = (guint)60;
  gst_options.bframes           = (guint)0;
  gst_options.img_width         = (guint)1920;
  gst_options.img_height        = (guint)1080;

  GSTThreadSafeQueue my_queue(20);
  VideoSourceGST gst_source_instance(&my_queue);
  VideoSinkGST gst_sink_instance(&gst_options, &my_queue);
  
  gst_source_instance.initialize();
  
  std::string gst_err_str;
  gst_sink_instance.initialize(gst_err_str);
  if (!gst_err_str.empty()) {
    std::cout << "err_str is: " << gst_err_str << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  if (signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
    perror("signal()");
    exit(1);
  }

  while (!done) {
    std::cout << "queue size is " << my_queue.get_size() << std::endl;
    sleep(1);
  }

  printf("got SIGINT\n");
}

void sigint_handler(int signum) { done = 1; }

Steps to reproduce
I am using a Kria SOM KV260 with the kv260-smartcam app loaded (e.g. sudo xmutil loadapp kv260-smartcam) and running in a custom docker container extended from xilinx/smartcam:2022.1
While inside the docker container, the above files may be placced in the same directory and built with:
g++ -o enc_test enc_test.cc video_sink_gst.cc `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4 gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-app-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0`


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
